# Average of empty list throws InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, linq

The following code

```
double avg = item?.TechnicianTasks?.Average(x => x.Rating) ?? 0
```

throws

> InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

the `item.TechnicianTasks` was supposed to be null, however I saw that it is an empty list, however why wouldn't the average just be zero? I'm not understanding the exception.

Comment: because `Average` = `Sum` / `Count`, but `Count` is 0 for an empty sequence and you can't divide by zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to it - it's just how the code was written.  [Take a look at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads) and you'll see -

> Exceptions
>
> ArgumentNullException - source is null.
>
> InvalidOperationException - source contains no elements.

Makes sense though.  You can't get an average from zero items.

Comment: Well I know that I could check if the list has any items before getting the average, but however isn't it do do it in a single line then?

Comment: `.DefaultIfEmpty(0)`